# Using paralist in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, enumitem, paralist

Using:

`compactbiblio.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{compactenum}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\cite{Master14}.
\item Nam dui ligula\cite{Lord14}.
\end{compactenum}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{compactbiblio}
\end{document}
```

and

`compactbiblio.bib`

```
@Article{Master14,
  author = "J. Master",
  title = "Compaction of enumerations",
  journal = "The basis for tree saving",
  year = "2014"
}

@Article{Lord14,
  author = "K. Lord",
  title = "Streamlining in typesetting",
  journal = "Patterns before substance",
  year = "2014"
}
```

and running the quad

```
pdflatex compactbiblio
bibtex compactbiblio
pdflatex compactbiblio
pdflatex compactbiblio
```

We obtain

[image: large bibliography interitem spacing]

How can one obtain an identical iter-item spacing in compactenum and within the bibliography without manually adjusting `\baselinestretch`, etc..?

Using enumitem instead of paralist is also good.

Comment: It would be much easier to work on this problem if you put together a minimum working example that illustrates the spacing you currently see and the spacing you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @cslstr I've now done so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `thebibliography` environment to have `\parskip` and `\itemsep` equal to `0pt` so to have a "compact" list:

```
\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%
  \oldthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{auth00a,
  author = {Author, A},
  journal = {Journal A},
  title = {MyBook A},
  year = {2000}
}
@article{auth00b,
  author = {Author, B},
  journal = {Journal B},
  title = {MyBook B},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography[1]{%
  \oldthebibliography{#1}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}
\begin{compactitem}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{compactitem}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's all right, I guess. But we'd be relying on paralist also using 0pt.